# Clone rigid body world across scenes?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cache

I created a 2000 frame animation with a rigid body sim. In order to have different camera angles I created several linked scenes with different cameras and movements per scene.

I re-ran my simulation on Scene 1, and now it is different on all of my other scenes. The frame settings are different and the animation stops early and some items have been replaced with other items (maybe unrelated)

How do I re-sync the rigid body world of these scenes? They are all set to use the same rigid body world.

Comment: Hello, what kind of new scene have you created, was it a full copy or linked copy? Also if you just want new angles, why don't you simply create new cameras in the same scene?

Comment: "normally" as moonboots proposed, you would 1) bake the rigid body simulation (so that it stays the same) and 2) add cameras with angles + camera animation in the same scene and then just render both cameras or more (you can do this at the same time with output settings -> stereoscopy -> multiview

Comment: I have many overlapping camera angles which share the same frame ranges. I place a marker on the timeline to select the active camera, set the frame range for that camera and then later I run the command line renderer for all of the scenes so it can render all scenes back to back. The stereoscopic thing does me no good when i have 3+ cameras within the same frame range. @moonboots i mentioned i created a linked scene in the original post.

Comment: I have the same problem. I didn't realise rigid body world does not transfer between linked scenes. In my case, I have 2 scenes per camera angle, one for a cycles render, and the other for an Eevee render of volumetrics (with everything in the cycles scene held out) which I composite later. So its important that the rigid body world be exactly the same between the 2 scenes. In the rigid body world settings, it looks like you can select the rigid body collection, but it does not work...the collections do not operate on the linked rigid bodies if they were added to the scene later.

Comment: One possible solution is to bake to keyframes. Keyframes will link between the scenes.